# Opening default text editor in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was writing a shell script and ran into a problem: Is there a way to open a file using the user's specified text editor?

Comment: Be careful: some users will set EDITOR to a program that daemonizes itself, and your script will not be able to easily wait for them to finish.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Why would anyone do such a thing? Could you please give me a scenario where that is appropriate?

Comment: @kraxor, I would say it is never appropriate, but some people do crazy things.  It is not unusual for someone to want a gui editor that spawns a new window.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The user's chosen editor should be in `$EDITOR`, but you must still choose a sane default.

```
"${EDITOR:-vi}" file.txt
```

Comment: You might want to do more fallbacks, eg: ${EDITOR:-${VISUAL:-vi}}

Comment: What about `${FCEDIT:-${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}}`?  Giving VISUAL preference over `$EDITOR` containing `ed` seems like a good idea.  `$FCEDIT` was the env var for `ksh` (probably still is), where the `fc` command is used to access history; it is also recognized by `bash`.

Comment: Anything more consise then? `DEFAULTEDITOR="\`command -v nano >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'nano' || echo 'vi'\`" && echo "${FCEDIT:-${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-$DEFAULTEDITOR}}}" && "${FCEDIT:-${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-$DEFAULTEDITOR}}}" file.txt`

Answer (score 10):

Ignacio's right (though arguably, the fallback should be `ed`, which POSIX requires to be present, although it's essentially only useful to old-timers).

If you're thinking about graphical editors, `xdg-open file.txt` is what you're after.

Comment: POSIX requires `vi` too, doesn't it?  Or is that just the User Portability Utilities option to POSIX where `ed` is not.  But +1 for mentioning `ed`.

Comment: Under the discussion of the environment variable `POSIX2_UPE` (old name for feature was User Portability Extension, UPE) in [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html), there is a list of the features that are in the UPU: '_The list of utilities in the User Portability Utilities option is as follows: `bg`, `ex`, `fc`, `fg`, `jobs`, `more`, `talk`, `vi`._  So, in theory, if you have the `fc` command, you should also have `vi` available.

Answer (score 4):

note: `xdg-open file.xml` will open in a Web-Browser, most likely.
So, try;

```
    # select your default sensible-editor from all installed editors, or not.
    select-editor
    # Open Default Text Editor
    sensible-editor file.xml
```

Comment: what distribution is this? both commands are not available on my system