# How do I invoke a text editor from a command line program like git does?

Tags: python, linux, command-line-interface

Some `git` commands, `git commit` for example, invoke a command-line based text editor (such as `vim` or `nano`, or other) pre-filled with some values and, after the user saves and exists, do something with the saved file.

How should I proceed to add this functionality to a Python similar command-line program, at Linux?

---

Please don't stop yourself for giving an answer if it does not use Python, I will be pretty satisfied with a generic abstract answer, or an answer as code in another language.

Comment: What language? What operating system?

Comment: Yeah, that's important. I edited the question.

Comment: The choice of editor is usually provided by the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables (and in some cases, by an application specific variable too, such as `GIT_EDITOR`). So you would need to get the user's preference from the environment, create a temp file and execute the chosen editor on that file.

Comment: @isedev: why did you give a perfectly valid answer as a comment? Why not write an answer?

Comment: A proper answer should possibly include an example of how to execute the editor in Python, etc... Feel free to compose an more complete answer - I'm not concerned about you re-using the content's of my comment.

Comment: In addition to the comment of isedev: The "system" function might be useful. Or one of the exec... functions. Or the subprocess module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725238/opening-default-text-editor-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will depend on what editor you have, which environment variable the editor might possibly be found in and if the editor takes any command line parameters.

This is a simple solution that works on windows without any environment variables or command line arguments to the editor. Modify as is needed.

```
import subprocess
import os.path

def start_editor(editor,file_name):

    if not os.path.isfile(file_name): # If file doesn't exist, create it
        with open(file_name,'w'): 
            pass

    command_line=editor+' '+file_name # Add any desired command line args
    p = subprocess.Popen(command_line)
    p.wait()

file_name='test.txt' # Probably known from elsewhere
editor='notepad.exe' # Read from environment variable if desired

start_editor(editor,file_name)

with open(file_name,'r') as f: # Do something with the file, just an example here
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned **Linux**.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Don't have a linux system at hand to test on, but should work by changing 'notepad.exe' to eg. 'gedit'.